# Webview : Renderer process crash detected (code -1)

Tags: android, webview

After the latest [release of chrome](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2023/08/chrome-for-android-update.html) this month, webview is crashing on exit from webview everytime. Is anyone else noticing it? Removing webview.destroy() doesn't make a difference.

```
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 115.0.5790.166 (code 579016630)
...
E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(156)] Renderer process (23192) crash detected (code -1).
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, but my WebView is created in the `Service`. And if I don't call `WebView.destroy()` I don't get this error. But I see this WebView in the Google Chrome's `chrome://inspect` as "detached".

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue. I was getting

```
[ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(154)] Renderer process (27035) crash detected
```

In my case at least, it turned out that creating multiple WebViews was causing this error. Which was also causing that the evaluateJavascript (added with addJavascriptInterface) to stop calling back suddenly.
Now I create one WebView instance and I pass it when needed, after this the error message is not showing up anymore and evaluateJavascript is working as expected.